# When installing Apache Tomcat error shows while choosing path for Java

Tags: java, tomcat, installation, runtime-error

While installing the Apache Tomcat, when I'm choosing the path for Java, it shows error like "No Java Virtual Machine found in folder". How can I solve this issue and where can I download essential file to install tomcat. Any Solution ??

Answer (score 1):

i know this is late but maybe it could be useful for someone , 
apache tomcat requires the JRE installed in your machine , here is the link from oracle for jre 8:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the root of your java folder in the Tomcat installation wizard.

So use `C:\Program Files\java\jdk-11.0.15.10-hotspot` or equivalent. Do not point to inner directories like `\bin` or `\bin\server` & `\bin\client`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your problem related to wrong `JAVA_HOME` setting.

In Windows, from Command Line you can just type `set ja` and ensure that `JAVA_HOME` points to correct Java installation

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on "My Computer" or "This PC" and select "Properties."
Click on "Advanced system settings."
In the System Properties window, click on the "Environment Variables" button.
Under System Variables, click "New" and add a variable named JAVA_HOME with the path to your JDK installation directory (e.g., C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291).
Click "OK" to save the changes.

for me it worked try it on ur systems